# PostgreSQL, Postgis geometry field

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In my table (coordinates) I have x, y z coordinates, and I want to create a new colmun which contains the point.

```
id |x   |y   | z   |        
----------------------
1  |145 |9.6 |12.4 |
```

So I run the following commands:

```
ALTER TABLE coordinates ADD COLUMN point geometry;
UPDATE point SET = 'POINT(x y z)';
```

But I got this error :

```
<-- parse error at
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` command is wrong, suspect you want something like this:

(`ST_MakePoint` may not be the constructor you want, but I don't think `POINT` exists).

```sql
UPDATE coordinates SET point = ST_MakePoint(x,y,z);
```

Comment: @Wave1988 if it solves your question please mark it as answered